# How to return array of string from java web services?

Tags: java, soap

I am trying to return an array of objects from a web service

```
[WebMethod]
public String[] getArray()
{
    String v[]=null;
    v[0]="String one";
    v[1]="String Two";
    return v;
 }
```

It won't return the array but simply returns the string '[]',
If its not possible to return an array of string, are there any other ways to return an array of some objects?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you wrote causes a NPE

Comment: Change String v[]=null; to String v[] = new String[2];

Comment: That code looks like C#, not Java. Which is it?

Comment: @Uzochi Please write your comment as an answer :)